# How do I throw CacheException when there is not a cached value

Tags: exception, caching, flutter, dart

I am having Issues trying to throw a cacheException if there isn't any json available (i.e. there is not an internet connection). I am using Flutter and I am running a test on the function. My code block looks like this.

```
  Future<PostModel> getLastPost() {
    final jsonString = sharedPreferences.getString(CACHED_POST);
    if (jsonString != null) {
      return Future.value(PostModel.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString)));
    } else {
    /*The error is thrown here->*/  throw CacheException();
    }
  }
```

Flutter giver me this error

```
  Expected: throws <Instance of 'TypeMatcher<CacheException>'>
    Actual: <Closure: () => Future<PostModel>>
     Which: threw <Instance of 'CacheException'>
            stack package:lookr_flutter/features/social/data/datasources/social_local_data_source.dart 26:7  SocialLocalDataSourceImpl.getLastPost
                  features/social/data/datasources/social_local_data_source_test.dart 46:26                  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                  package:test_api                                                                           expect
                  package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 229:3                                          expect
                  features/social/data/datasources/social_local_data_source_test.dart 46:9                   main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!